# Three divs in a responsive iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, responsive-design

I have three `div`s and this Google Maps `iframe` code with the following CSS:

```
#contact_map { border-radius: 200px; width: 320px; height: 320px; overflow: hidden; max-width: 100%; position: relative; right: 0px; }
#contact_map_fake { border-radius: 200px; width: 320px; height: 320px; top:0px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 3px 5px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); pointer-events:none; position: absolute; border: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.6);
}
#contact_map_container { border-radius: 200px; overflow: hidden; width: 320px; height: 320px;   }
```

How can I change the CSS to make this responsive, so that the map jumps under the other `div`s when I view the page on an iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in css using @media tags

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait){
  /* some CSS here */
  /*define css for all divs*/

}

/* #### Mobile Phones Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){
  /* some CSS here */
  /*define css for all divs*/
}

/* #### Mobile Phones Portrait or Landscape #### */
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
  /* some CSS here */
  /*define css for all divs*/
}
```

Comment: hello, i mean in the browser when you change the size. the map has to fit down.

Comment: @Carsten you told How can I change the CSS to make this responsive, so that the map jumps under the other divs when I view the page on an iPhone?

Answer (score 0):

use css media query @media

```
   @media all and (max-width: 640px){
 #contact_map{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
}
```